# ASIHTTPRequest failed when calling JSONValue: Unrecognised leading character at offset 0

Tags: ios, json, asihttprequest

As the title said.
My code is below:

```
NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
NSLog(@"%@", responseString);
NSDictionary *responseDict = [responseString JSONValue];
```

and I print the response, it begins with this:

```
2014-01-05 00:50:42.409 PromoTest[1277:a0b] 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>èæä½è² - ä½ çä½è²å¨ä¸çï¼</title>
<meta name="Keywords" content="ä½è²,è¿å¨,èæä½è²,èæ" />
<meta name="Description" 
…
```

So, my question is, where does the json string begin?
Thank you very much! I'm new with http and JSON.

Comment: There's no JSON string there anywhere.

Comment: then how i get JSON string? The WEB server doesn't support JSON?

Comment: That's between you and your web server.  Some support JSON, some don't.

Comment: @Hot Licks thanks for you opinion! I've got it.

Answer (score 2):

Your response string looks like HTML instead of straight JSON. You aren't actually showing any JSON in your example. Make sure the server is sending JSON including a Content-type of application/json and/or that that is what you are accepting.

Comment: would you please reply me the questions below?

Answer (score 0):

@valheru  I can't control the peer web server. I've got the answer, so I have to parse html(based on xml?).
I find a tutorial, and is useful for me:
how to parse html on ios
http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios